# How to custom bottomSheet sliding

Tags: android, android-view, androiddesignsupport

I just start with BottomSheet. I've copied BottomSheetBehavior class and find where is function that set state for bottomSheet to be expanded or collapsed when user drag it up/down. I need the bottomSheet just stay at drag position or you can advise me the easier ways

Answer (score 0):

You'd better not copy BottomSeetBehaviour class.

1. It is included in support design library, so add a dependency:

   `compile 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'`
2. Create a layout which you want to be a bottom sheet.
   You can set a peak height (height in collapsed state) as `app:behavior_peekHeight="80dp"` 
   (or in code). Make sure it's parent is CoordinatorLayout.
3. In code find the layout you want to slide and create a bottom sheet behavior:

   `BottomSheetBehavior behavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(yourSlidingLayout);`

Then set a BottomSheetCallback on it to track state changes.

Comment: I've reached this step. I just wonder that how to set  position to bottomSheet by slideOffset when drags not only fully expanded or collapsed

Comment: As I mentioned, use app:behavior_peekHeight for your sliding layout. Or behavior.setPeakHeight() in code

Comment: how to get the height of the dragged position in order to set it.